# How do I write nested styles?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack

I am using react.js and i have simple rules for my webpack

```
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                {loader: 'style-loader'},
                {loader: 'css-loader', options: {modules: true}}
            ]
        }
```

all i do, i process my css styles with help of style and css loaders, so i can write css in modules, everything works fine but i can't understand how to write nested styles, for example i have jsx code like this

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import ButtonCSS from "./button.css";
import HeaderCSS from "./header.css";
import ArticleCSS from "./article.css";

const Button = ({title}) => {
    return (
        <div className={ButtonCSS.defaultButtonStyle}>
            {title}
        </div>
    );
};

const Page = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <header className={HeaderCSS.defaultStyle}>
                <Button title="Search" />
            </header>
            <article className={ArticleCSS.defaultStyle}>
                <Button title="Registration" />
            </article>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Page />,
    document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

here i want what my default project button would be red for search, and orange for registration, but styles for button and for header are in different .css files, and they are compiled to random hashes like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div data-reactroot="">
        <header class="_1drImxMAqFTeL1TQCthA-D">
            <div class="_1Itfki2yr_IamWL2zkYKwW">Registration</div>
        </header>
        <article>
            <div class="_1Itfki2yr_IamWL2zkYKwW">Registration</div>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>
```

so i can't just simply write something like

```
header .magic {
    do something ...
}
```

if i'll start using `:global` in all my .css files, what will be the point of using modules at all?

Answer (score 0):

You should use composition: https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules#composition.

This way, you will have both your classes extending a class containing all the common css.

Comment: So to change style of button i need to create additional style in `button.css`, then compose style from `header.css` and then somehow use new `button.css` composed from `header.css` style in react component, and repeat all this each time i want to use my default project button somewhere?